# Is there an appropriate StackExchange site to show my code to check best practices?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

If you're trying to learn a new framework or programming language, documentation and examples usually aren't enough.

In my case it's Django. There are so many ways to create multiple types of users and registration etc. that a newbie can get very confused. I'm curious, whether or not this is a good place to put my (simple) code to get some comments on what I've done wrong, what should be done differently, etc.

Stack Overflow is probably not good for this kind of question. Is there another Stack Exchange site that's good for this?

Comment: If you haven't even begun coding and are trying to figure out how to begin with a particular project, this isn't the place. Also probably a good idea to not include "best practices" in the question.

Comment: Yes, "best practices" and "best way" are opinion based questions. It's better to avoid the word "best" altogether unless you provide an objective measure for it.

Comment: Both meta sites have some interesting questions on the subject: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265928/is-a-best-practice-question-off-topic and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing

Comment: One of these days I want to see a question asking for the worst way to do something.

Comment: @TinyGiant That kind of question would probably belong on [codegolf.se].

Comment: @200_success That was more to say that no one is ever looking for the worst way to do something (unless you're on PPCG), so why specify that you want the "best" way to do something? Why not just ask how to do that thing?

Comment: @TinyGiant I tried to ask myself that many times, it seems to boil down to people being terribly misinformed that programming is easy and thus you can generalize everything.

Comment: Define "what I do wrong". Inefficiencies are welcome at the accepted answer, bugs and segmentation faults not.

Comment: [Read this about Best Practices before you ask about them. Even on code review, that would be pretty contentious as opinionated.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing)

Comment: @BSMP - if there is an objective measurement best is relative unless the measurement case is extremely narrow and specific. Best in space and time or space or time? Best is just too broad to be interpretated the same way by everyone.

Comment: @TinyGiant Sometimes people don't want the "best" way to do something because that may not be the most understandable from a learning point. As already pointed out, "best" is somewhat subjective, but objective qualifiers exist as well, such as "fastest" or "smallest," etc... If the code is the "best" it can be, the requester might not know how to use it or how to maintain it.

Comment: Honestly if you want the fastest answer or smallest answer you should take the answers you get and compare them in that way. Those words are useless in the question itself. @stix

Comment: *Best in space and time or space or time?* @JarrodRoberson - An objective measure would specify but I don't disagree that folks would be better off just not using the word at all.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Yes, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

You can post your code on here for others to review and offer advice and improvements. They have [this helpful guide](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) for Stack Overflow users to learn about how the site works.

Stack Overflow is more aimed at code that *doesn't* work.

Comment: In fact, code review requires that the code actually work.

Comment: "code that doesn't work" *and* practical answerable programming problems.

Comment: @Braiam, you mean "Why doesn't my code solve world hunger" is not an acceptable question for SO? :P

Comment: @CaptJak more like "How do I get my code to stop playing Xbox and get a job?"

Answer (score 27):

If you have working code and want to get suggestions and reviews then [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is proper place for such posts.

On the other hand if you have code that does not work properly then you should stick to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Not that this is important, but I would like to know what is wrong with this and other answer to justify down votes. Is there any other site better than Code Review for reviewing working code.

Comment: @Celeo That is not what I was asking. I was asking why down votes on both answers (that are practically identical in content). And just for the record, I posted my answer first, but difference was insignificant. And other answer got accepted and upvoted more. I am fine with that.